# PegaRULES mining and testing

Tags: pega

new to the job and I'm sourcing for information relating to PegaRULES. Hope someone with first-hand experience using Pega can help me please.

My business rules are in a COBOL-system. Is there any way Pega can facilitate the transfer of rules over to their system or must each business rule be entered all over.

Should I switch vendors subsequently, how can the business rules in PegaRULES be exported out?

What is the scope of testing PegaRULES is able to do? I went through a few of their online courses and I'm certain it can verify and validate rules. What about testing the integration between Pega and other applications?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simply import and export rules for different systems.

The rules in a Pega system are not only "business rules", but e.g. "user interface rules", "process rules" and "data model rules" as well. I don't see how you would split up your COBOL code into e.g. section rules that can be used to autogenerate HTML5.

Regarding your second question: it's not possible to use the exported Pega code (rules) on different systems. What you can plan for however is offering the BPM case management and processing via REST or SOAP service for other systems to consume.